# Angular2 Material Dialog css, dialog size

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Angular2 material team recently released the MDDialog https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/README.md

I'd like to change the looking and feel about the angular2 material's dialog. For example, to change the fixed size of the popup container and make it scrollable, change the background color, so forth. What's the best way to do so? Is there a css that I can play with?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can inspect the dialog element with dev tools and see what classes are applied on mdDialog.

For example, `.md-dialog-container` is the main classe of the MDDialog and has padding: 24px

you can create a custom CSS to overwrite whatever you want

```
.md-dialog-container {
      background-color: #000;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px
}
```

In my opinion this is not a good option and probably goes against Material guide but since it doesn't have all features it has in its previous version, you should do what you think is best for you.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding a DIV and style on that.

Comment: This is not working with this dialog - https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog  .. changes are not applied

Comment: @bukajcihaj as far as I know the css class of angular material has changed a little, so, as I said in my answer, use dev tools to see what classes are applied to the dialog and overtwrite them. You can also look at the answer below.

Comment: Good direction, but I'm wondering now *where* to put the styling for a dialog called programatically. If I put in the component I'm populating the dialog with, it does no good.

Comment: @Elmer Dantas, thanks, that could work for now. I was interested in styling the modal just for that component, rather than all modals. I guess the only way to do that now is with the MdDialogConfig options, although it doesn't include padding yet.

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle you can create a specific css rule just for this component...but I don't get one thing: why the component's css is not working?

Comment: Recently ran into a similar problem where I couldn't get a specific material class to style (even with specificity and using !important). Some of the material classes has ViewRule.Blocked (or something like that) which basically encapsulates the styles to that component so it ignores any other styling. The trick is to use `::ng-deep`. for example, `::ng-deep .mat-sidenav-container { height: auto; }`. Still trying to understand this but this solution worked for me.

Comment: where should I place the md-dialog-container class? and where should I use it?

Comment: @FurqanShakir you should check dev tools if the class is still the same..the answer/angular has changed since the question was posted

Comment: @mwilson`::ng-deep .[cdk|md class] { ... }` worked for me - great find - wish this wasn't buried in just a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that if you are adding this kind of `::ng-deep` rule in your component - it will apply GLOBAL styling, meaning that if you do `::ng-deep` on class that exist on all of the angular modals - all of those modals will receive that styling as soon as you launch that component for the first time.

Answer (score 83):

There are two ways which we can use to change size of your MatDialog component in angular material

**1) From Outside Component Which Call Dialog Component**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';


dialogRef: MatDialogRef <any> ;

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog() {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TestTemplateComponent, {
            height: '40%',
            width: '60%'
        });
        this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.dialogRef = null;
        });
    }
```

**2) From Inside Dialog Component. dynamically change its size**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>) { }

 ngOnInit() {
        this.dialogRef.updateSize('80%', '80%');
    }
```

use updateSize() in any function in dialog component. it will change dialog size automatically.

for more information check this link https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog

Comment: Is there any way to find the current size from inside the dialog component?

Answer (score 70):

Content in `md-dialog-content` is automatically scrollable.

You can manually set the size in the call to `MdDialog.open`

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(MyComponent, {
  height: '400px',
  width: '600px',
});
```

Further documentation / examples for scrolling and sizing:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Some colors should be determined by your theme. See here for theming docs:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

If you want to override colors and such, use Elmer's technique of just adding the appropriate css.

Note that you must have the HTML 5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` on your page for the size of your dialog to fit the contents correctly ( https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2351 )

Comment: What if I want to add more than height and width? Like border-radius, or background. Where do I put this css?

Comment: You can add relevant css like make use of `panelClass`

Answer (score 45):

With current version of Angular Material (6.4.7) you can use a custom class:

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
  panelClass: 'my-class'
});
```

Now put your class somewhere global (haven't been able to make this work elsewhere), e.g. in `styles.css`:

```
.my-class .mat-dialog-container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: lightcyan;
  color: #039be5;
}
```

Done!

Comment: This is very handy solution if you want to change certain dialog without affecting every dialog in your project.

Comment: This is the method I use in Angular 7 + Material 7. I have a followup question (Will make it an actual question if I can't find an answer anywhere): How can I set a maximum dialog width, IF the user is using a wide screen (monitor), but NOT if they're using a smaller viewport (a phone or portrait tablet, for example)?

Comment: @Ade You would have to use media [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) for that

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than the top answer as you can define a lot more properties than just height as well as you can use SCSS variables.

Answer (score 11):

sharing the latest on mat-dialog
two ways of achieving this... 
1) either you set the width and height during the open 
e.g.

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(NwasNtdSelectorComponent, {
    data: {
        title: "NWAS NTD"
    },
    width: '600px',
    height: '600px',
    panelClass: 'epsSelectorPanel'
});
```

or
2) use the `panelClass` and style it accordingly.

1) is easiest but 2) is better and more configurable.

Comment: @PrasadShinde you have to put the CSS class in your global Styles.css file (or presumably .scss if that's what you're using).

Comment: @PrasadShinde - no worries, it was only after I replied I spotted your comment was 6 months ago, and you'd probably figured that by now!!

Comment: Yes, but there are very few people who tried to post their opinion even if in such case.

Answer (score 5):

For the most recent version of Angular as of this post, it seems you must first create a MatDialogConfig object and pass it as a second parameter to dialog.open() because Typescript expects the second parameter to be of type MatDialogConfig.

```
const matDialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
matDialogConfig.width = "600px";
matDialogConfig.height = "480px";
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, matDialogConfig);
```

Answer (score 5):

**dialog-component.css**

This code works perfectly for me, other solutions don't work. 
Use the ::ng-deep shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views. The ::ng-deep combinator works to any depth of nested components, and it applies to both the view children and content children of the component.

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    height: 400px !important;
    width: 400px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really what I need to make my dialog have default size.

Comment: Bad advice: ::ng-deep, /deep/ and so on are all deprecated. If you do this now, it'll end in tears when they actually remove it.

Comment: Doesn't work if dim %...

Comment: @DennisK, it was worked for 2020. I know that it is deprecated for now. To solve this in the newer Angular version, add these styles to global styles.scss.

Comment: @AndriiVynnyk It has been deprecated since at least 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep

Comment: @DennisK not all use the last angular version. If my answer is still gaining a rating, it is still relevant to someone.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `/deep/`, because your CSS may not see your modal class. For example, if you want to customize `.modal-dialog`

```
/deep/.modal-dialog {
  width: 75% !important;
}
```

But this code will modify all your modal-windows, better solution will be

```
:host {
  /deep/.modal-dialog {
  width: 75% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: For people reading this in 2018, /deep and all its variants are DEPRECATED

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
dialogRef.updateSize("300px", "300px");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also let angular material solve the size itself depending on the content.
This means you don't have to cloud your TS files with sizes that depend on your UI. You can keep these in the HTML/CSS.

**my-dialog.html**

```html
<div class="myContent">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title fxLayoutAlign="center">Your title</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" fxLayout="column">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
    </div mat-dialog-content>
  </form>
</div>
```

**my-dialog.scss**

```
.myContent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

**my-component.ts**

```
const myInfo = {};
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { data: myInfo });
```

Answer (score 1):

On smaller screen's like laptop the dialog will shrink. To auto-fix, try the following option

http://answersicouldntfindanywhereelse.blogspot.com/2018/05/angular-material-full-size-dialog-on.html

Additional Reading
https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

Thanks to the solution in answersicouldntfindanywhereelse (2nd para).
 it worked for me.

Following is needed

import { Breakpoints, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout'

Answer (score 0):

**component.ts**

```
const dialog = matDialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  data: {
    panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container',
    autoFocus: false,
  },
});
```

**styles.scss**

```
// mobile portrait:
@media (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 599px) {
  // DIALOG:
  // width:
  .cdk-overlay-pane {
    max-width: 100vw !important;
  }
  // padding
  .custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).