# md-dialog size Material for Angular 2 troubleshooting

Tags: angular-material2

When I open a Material dialog (`MdDialog.open(MyDialogComponent)`), the dialog that opens spans the entire height of my screen.

When I remove `height:100%` from `.md-dialog-container` in Chrome inspector, the height is adjusted to fit the contents perfectly.

But the source code of md-dialog makes it look like this is intentional:

```
md-dialog-container {
  ...
  // The dialog container should completely fill its parent overlay element.
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

I've already removed Material for Angular 1 from my project to avoid CSS conflicts with Material for Angular 2. (The old css was making the width overly large too.)

What could cause this or how do I troubleshoot it?

My dialog component is simple:

```
<h2 md-dialog-title>...</h2>

<md-dialog-content>
   ...
</md-dialog-content>

<md-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button... />
</md-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My page was missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2351

See this answer for more info about dialogs:
[Angular2 Material Dialog css, dialog size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595276/angular2-material-dialog-css-dialog-size/41864979#41864979)