# Overriding Angular Material Size and Styling of md-dialog-container

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material and I am using md-dialog for my popups for my gallery. The default animation and styling looks nice. However, I would like to change the width and height of size of the `md-dialog-container`? which is hidden. Only added when I click the modal and when you open the chrome dev tools you can see the `md-dialog-container` appearing. Do include how to override the rest of the styling.

Much appreciate with some help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Material Dialog css, dialog size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595276/angular2-material-dialog-css-dialog-size)

Answer (score 90):

From the official documentation:

> **Styling overlay components**
>
> Overlay-based components have a panelClass
> property (or similar) that can be used to target the overlay pane.

You can override the default dialog container styles by adding a css class in your global **`styles.css`**. For example:

```
.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
    /* add your styles */
}
```

After that, you'll need to providies you css class as a **`panelClass`** parameter to your dialog:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container' })
```

Read this [**official documentation**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md) for more information.

Comment: Does it only work in style.scss?  can it work in component scss file?

Comment: For me it only worked after adding ::ng-deep like this: ::ng-deep div.my-panel .mat-dialog-container { ... }

Comment: It is very important that you apply these styles to `styles.css`. Because I tried to apply them on the component's style and it didn't work at all. So always make sure you put this piece of code inside your global styles to avoid hours of frustrations.

Comment: if you apply `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in `your-dialogue-component.ts` then you can move the definition of your dialogue `panelClass` styles from `styles.css` to `your-dialogue.component.css`

Comment: @AlexNazarevych setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` will affect all the dialogs since the styles will not be encapsulated.

Answer (score 29):

There is **no need to add global styles**.

You can add this to your own component style:

```
::ng-deep .my-custom-dialog-class {
  mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

> Make sure there is no "." (dot class selector) for `mat-dialog-container` because you must use the html tag selector.

Then when you open the dialog, add your class in `panelClass` property:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  data: {},
  panelClass: 'my-custom-dialog-class'
});
```

By using a custom `panelClass`, this ensures only dialogs opened with that class will be affected, even using `ng::deep`.

Comment: I like this better because I can keep my styles with the dialog component which can be reused rather than adding a lot of content to styles.css

Comment: @Alisson Will this leak css styles into other dialog components, as we don't use :host ::ng-deep

Answer (score 7):

You can change width/height of the modal by setting the values in the open() method, something like the following:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
  height: '300px'
  width: '400px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WorkModalComponent, {
       width: '1200px',
       data: workObj,
       panelClass: 'my-dialog-container-class' // Replace with your actual dialog container class
    });
```

add the panelClass to your Dialog and add your CSS style to this class.

Answer (score 0):

If all that wouldn't work, you can try

```
const e: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(this.element.nativeElement.parentElement.id);
e.style.display = 'flex';

e.style.padding = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with Angular 13 following Faisal's solution however I had to add: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to my `@Component` declaration that is being used as a dialog:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-spinner-dialog',
  templateUrl: './progress-spinner-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-spinner-dialog.component.css'],
  // this needed to override the mat-dialog-container CSS class
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Without this reference to `ViewEncapsulation.None` I was not able to get the CSS override to work. I found this great hint here: [Learn Angular 11 MatDialog Basics](https://www.developer.com/languages/javascript/angular-11-matdialog-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to insert width/height like that:

```
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
        dialogConfig.data = { title: 'Register a doctor shekh' };
        dialogConfig.height = '450px';
        dialogConfig.width = '700px';
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddDoctorComponent, dialogConfig);
```